# Is OOP really helping?

Tags: oop, drupal-8

I am trying to create a simple module in Drupal 8 and it looks like what was really easy in Drupal 7 is now unbelievably complicated. It can be done with help of StackOverflow and Google, however, one example:

Getting field values from node like this:

```
'name' => $node->get('title')->getValue(),
'body' => $node->get('body')->getValue(),
'image' => file_create_url($node->field_fotografia->entity->getFileUri()),
```

Why is the way of getting image field different from the title and body? How do I know what way to use and how will I know in future if there is any other way for other type of field?

Answer (score 0):

the logic is quite simple

```
$node->get('body')->getValue();
```

means: get property value of field "body"

D7 equivalent is

```
$node['body'][$language][$index]['value];
```

which is straigh forward

now the other example

```
$node->field_fotografia->entity->getFileUri()
```

means: get property uri of entity stored in field "field_fotografia" since the image is not a property value but a separate entity; actualy I believe that $node->get('field_fotografia')->getValue() returns the image id which make sense. Same model applies for all entity references (multifield, paragraphs, other nodes, etc).